# Which compiler(compiler location) does weblogic 11g use to compile JSP files?

Tags: jsp, weblogic

Hi can anyone please tell me which compiler(compiler location) does weblogic 11g use to compile JSP files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is called **weblogic.rmic**. You should be able to find the exact location with a simple search. You can find more information on the compiler on [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13721/rmi_rmic.htm#WLRMI133).

Comment: the good tool is weblogic.appc and not weblogic.rmic
[weblogic.appc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13719/appc_ejbc.htm#EJBPG1089)